# Any option for mocking custom metadata records using fflib-ApexMocks and fflib-apex-common?

Tags: apex, fflib, apexmock

Given a project based on `fflib-apex-common` and using `fflib-ApexMocks` for unit testing, I would like to mock Custom Metadata records and stop using real org values. Custom metadata queries are encapsulated into 'configuration' classes using static methods. Following an example:

```
public with sharing class AppointmentConfiguration {

    public static Integer getMinutesBlockedAfterAppoitment(){
        String value = AppointmentSettings__mdt
            .getInstance('MINUTES_BLOCKED_AFTER_APPOITMENT').value__c;
        return Integer.valueOf(value);
    }
        [...]
}
```

Therefore, in the service layer:

```
AppointmentConfiguration.getMinutesBlockedAfterAppoitment();
```

Is there any option to mock it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me, it totally makes sense to get a record of `AppointmentSettings__mdt` from the selector's method so that it can be [canonically mocked](https://andyinthecloud.com/2015/03/29/unit-testing-apex-enterprise-patterns-and-apexmocks-part-2/) using `fflib-ApexMocks` in unit tests:

1. Create an `AppointmentSettingsSelector` class:

```
public with sharing class AppointmentSettingsSelector extends fflib_SObjectSelector {

    public override SObjectType getSObjectType() {
        return AppointmentSettings__mdt.SObjectType;
    }

    public override List<SObjectField> getSObjectFieldList() {
        return new List<SObjectField>{
                AppointmentSettings__mdt.Value__c
        };
    }

    public AppointmentSettings__mdt byDeveloperName(String devName) {
        return AppointmentSettings__mdt.getInstance(devName);
    }
}
```

2. Set Up the [`Application` class](https://quirkyapex.com/2017/12/03/fflib-application-structure/) to inject dependencies in run-time.

```
public with sharing class Application {

    public static final fflib_Application.SelectorFactory SELECTOR
        = new fflib_Application.SelectorFactory(
            new Map<SObjectType, Type>{
                AppointmentSettings__mdt.SObjectType => AppointmentSettingsSelector.class
            }
        );
}
```

3. Delegate querying the `AppointmentSettings__mdt` record to the injected `AppointmentSettingsSelector` instance:

```
public with sharing class SomeClass {

   public static void someMethod() {
       AppointmentSettingsSelector selector = (AppointmentSettingsSelector) 
           Application.SELECTOR.newInstance(AppointmentSettings__mdt.SObjectType);
       String value = selector.byDeveloperName('MINUTES_BLOCKED_AFTER_APPOITMENT')
           .value__c;
       [...]
   }
        
}
```

4. Set up a Unit Test method:

```
@IsTest
static void test() {
    // Mocks
    fflib_ApexMocks mocks = new fflib_ApexMocks();
    AppointmentSettingsSelector selectorMock = (AppointmentSettingsSelector)
        mocks.mock(AppointmentSettingsSelector.class);
    
    // Instantiating and editing a CMT record are allowed in memory within Apex,
    // but DML operations are not allowed, although it is enough for mocking.
    AppointmentSettings__mdt settingsMock = new AppointmentSettings__mdt();
    settingsMock.Value__c = 'mock value';
    // Given
    Application.SELECTOR.setMock(selectorMock);
    mocks.startStubbing();        
    mocks.when(selectorMock.sObjectType())
        .thenReturn(AppointmentSettings__mdt.SObjectType);
    mocks.when(selectorMock.byDeveloperName('MINUTES_BLOCKED_AFTER_APPOITMENT'))
        .thenReturn(settingsMock);
    mocks.stopStubbing();
}
```

Comment: I couldn't have said it better!  Sometimes, you need to use the JSON serialize/deserialize approach to mock the MDT (fflib_ApexMocksUtil or its equivalent) as you can't use assignment statements for some of the fields